# Does Laraven's sanctum replace the default authentication?

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I've been browsing many questions related to using multi-auth, sanctum and SPA. I've also read the documentation multiple times. I'm confused about how this works.

Currently I have 2 route groups: `web` and `api`. Web group outputs different HTML templates and front-end content and so, and the API route generates content that is used to fill those templates.

I also have 2 different types of users, `admins` and `clients`. Each have access to certain routes of `web` and `api`.

I'm using 2 guards to protect the `web` routes, which works just fine:

```
'guards' => [
    'admin'        => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'client'        => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ],
],
```

And the providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'admins'    => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
    'clients'    => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Models\Client::class,
    ],
],
```

Now I have trouble protecting the API routes. I've followed the instructions, set `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header, added sanctum to middlewares but I always get a 401 response. I'm not sure how to setup my guards. Should I add 2 more guards to the array? Such as:

```
'guards' => [
    // Web
    'admin'        => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'client'        => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ],
    // API
    'sanctum_admin'     => [
        'driver'   => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'sanctum_client'    => [
        'driver'   => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ],
],
```

And then use add the `auth:sanctum_admin` middleware to my API routes? Because this doesn't work either. Should I remove the original guards and only use sanctum? Is this even possible to have multiple guards for both web and API? Really confused about how this works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're mixing API authorisation with user authentication.
I believe that by default the API-routes don't use sessions and need the use of API-tokens. Not 100% sure, did not play with sanctum yet

Comment: Sanctum provides 2 methods of authentications, Cookie based and Token based. I'm using the Cookie based method which uses `X-XSRF-TOKEN` cookie to authenticate the user.

Comment: Just quickly skimming the docs, but did you add the `api` middleware group to `app/Http/Kernel.php` as mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Yes, I've followed the steps multiple times. I think the issue might be with the multi-guard, since the guards are hardcoded in each model's `guard` property. I'm not sure.